# How do I duplicate blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been told that there's an easy way to duplicate blocks, but not how to do it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this only in creative mode.

If you are in creative mode selecting(clicking) a block with the *pick block* key (default *middle mouse button*) should give you a stack of that block.

Comment: Do you now a way to do this's in survival

Comment: @Thebestwithin I'm pretty certain there is no way to do this in survival, since you can't pull anything out of thin air in survival.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows how to duplicate blocks easily in survival mode.

Just throw the block and don't pick it up. Save and quit when its on the ground. Pick it up then use the 'X' on the Minecraft window to exit on the save and quit menu. Log back in and you'll have duplicated the block.

Comment: Note this only works on single player, you are exploiting the fact that the player data gets saved on `X` but not map data. You would have to restart the server to get a similar effect (basically you are inducing a "map rollback" while keeping your inventory from before the rollback.)

Comment: but it worked on me

Comment: I don't doubt it worked when you where playing single player, I am saying it will not work on multiplayer. For one thing you can't "Save and Quit" multiplayer, only "Disconnect"

Comment: oh ye thats true